# I need help to understand why my modal is making multiple eventlisteners if it's closed then opened again

Tags: javascript, html

OK so i make a modal in which i insert the options to alter the card properties like name, description and company. It's actually working fairly well except that when i open another modal without refreshing the page it doubles (then triplicates and so on) the number of requests it sends. And i dont know why. I'll link a video of my screen just so i can make myself more clear.

https://www.veed.io/view/17448fc2-7068-4419-87a2-395c528bbffa?sharingWidget=true&panel=share

here's the part of my code i think is important

```
function getAllDepartmentHandleButton() {
    const allDeleteButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.departmentContainer__content--card')

    allDeleteButtons.forEach(e => {
        e.addEventListener('click', (event) => {

            //console.log(event)
           
            if(event.target.classList.value == 'remove') {
                showRemoveDepartmentModal(event.target.id, event.target.alt)
            } else if(event.target.classList.value == 'edit') {
                showEditDepartmentModal(event.target.id)
            }
        })
    })
}

async function showEditDepartmentModal(departmentId) {
    let companyToEditid = 0
    const allDepartments = await getAllDepartments()
    const editModal = document.querySelector('.editDepartmentModal')
    const closeBtn = document.querySelector('.editDepartmentModal__container > img')
    const nameInput = document.querySelector('.editDepartmentModal__container--departmentName')
    const descriptionInput = document.querySelector('.editDepartmentModal__container--departmentDescription')
    const selectedCompanyInput = document.querySelector('.editDepartmentModal__container--company > span')
    const placeToAppend = document.querySelector('.editDepartmentModal__container--list')
    const showCompanyOptionsButton = document.querySelector('.editDepartmentModal__container--company')
    const dialogCompanyOptions = document.querySelector('.editDepartmentModal__container > dialog')
    const allCompanies = await getAllCompanies()
    const buttonSaveAlterations = document.querySelector('.editDepartmentModal__container--button')

    allCompanies.forEach(e => {
        placeToAppend.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `
    <li id="${e.uuid}">${e.name}</li>

    `)        
    })

    editModal.showModal()

    const selectedCompany = allDepartments.find(e => {
        if (e.uuid == departmentId) {
            return e
        }

    })

    closeBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
        editModal.close()
    })

    nameInput.value = selectedCompany.name
    descriptionInput.value = selectedCompany.description
    selectedCompanyInput.innerText = selectedCompany.companies.name
    selectedCompanyInput.id = departmentId

    showCompanyOptionsButton.addEventListener('click', ()=> {
        if(dialogCompanyOptions.open) {
            dialogCompanyOptions.close()
        } else {
            dialogCompanyOptions.show()

        }
        
    })

    placeToAppend.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        companyToEditid = event.target.id
        selectedCompanyInput.innerText = event.target.innerText
        dialogCompanyOptions.close()

    })

    buttonSaveAlterations.addEventListener('click', () => {
        if(nameInput.value == '' || descriptionInput.value == '') {
            alert('vazio')
        } else {

            editDepartmentFunction(nameInput.value, descriptionInput.value, companyToEditid)
            editModal.close()
        }
    })        
}


function editDepartmentFunction(test1, test2, test3) {
    console.log(test1, test2,test3)
}
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/globalStyles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/indexStyles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/AdminPageStyling copy.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/adminPagesModal.css">
    
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="titleAndMenuIcon">
            <span><span class="titleAndMenuIcon__bulelt">• </span>Kenzie Empresas</span>
            <button>Logout</button>
        </div>
    </header>

    <main>
        <div class="departmentContainer">
            <div class="departmentContainer__header">
                <span class="departmentContainer__header--title">Departamentos</span>
                <div class="departmentContainer__header--companiesSelect">
                    <span class="">Selecionar Empresa</span>
                    <img src="../files/down-arrow-svgrepo-com.svg" alt="">
                </div>
                <dialog class="departmentContainer__header--companiesModal">
                    <ul>
                        
                    </ul>

                </dialog>
                
                <div class="departmentContainer__header--create"><img src="../files/plusIcon.svg" alt=""><span>Criar</span></div>
            </div>
            <div class="departmentContainer__content">

            </div>

            
        </div>

        <div class="userContainer">
            <div class="userContainer__header">
                <span class="userContainer__header--title">Usuários Cadastrados</span>                
            </div>

            <div class="userContainer__content">          

            </div>

            
        </div>
    </main>


    <dialog class="createDepartmentModal">
        <div class="createDepartmentModal__container">
            <img src="../files/closebtnsvg.svg" alt="">
            <span class="createDepartmentModal__container--title">Criar Departemento</span>
            <input type="text" class="createDepartmentModal__container--departmentName" placeholder="Nome do Departamento">
            <input type="text" class="createDepartmentModal__container--departmentDescription" placeholder="Descrição">
            <div class="createDepartmentModal__container--company">
                <span>Selecionar Empresa</span>
                <img src="../files/down-arrow-svgrepo-com.svg" alt="">
                
            </div>
            <dialog class="createDepartmentModal__container--company__modal">
                <ul class="createDepartmentModal__container--company__modal--container">                    

                </ul>
            </dialog>
            <span class="createDepartmentModal__container--button">Criar Departamento</span>
    
        </div>
    </dialog>
    
    <dialog class="removeDepartmentModal">
        <div class="removeDepartmentModal__container">
            <span>mensagem aqui</span>
            <div>Continuar</div>
            <img src="../files/closebtnsvg.svg" alt="">

        </div>
    </dialog>

    <dialog class="editDepartmentModal">

        <div class="editDepartmentModal__container">
            <dialog><ul class="editDepartmentModal__container--list"></ul></dialog>
            <img src="../files/closebtnsvg.svg" alt="">
            <span class="editDepartmentModal__container--title">Editar Departamento</span>
            <input type="text" class="editDepartmentModal__container--departmentName" placeholder="Novo Nome do Departamento">
            <input type="text" class="editDepartmentModal__container--departmentDescription" placeholder="Nova Descrição">
            <div class="editDepartmentModal__container--company">
                <span>Selecionar Empresa</span>
                <img src="../files/down-arrow-svgrepo-com.svg" alt="">
                
            </div>
            <dialog class="editDepartmentModal__container--company__modal">
                <ul class="editDepartmentModal__container--company__modal--container">                    
    
                </ul>
            </dialog>
            <span class="editDepartmentModal__container--button">Salvar Alterações</span>
    
        </div>
    </dialog>
    
</body>
<script src="../scripts/AdminPageScript.js"></script>
</html>
```

I tried literally everything but the only thing that actually made it stop was refreshing the page. Which, of course, is not a propper alternative

Answer (score 0):

You are adding event listeners in the same function(`showEditDepartmentModal`) you are using to show the modal.

You have two options. One, clear the event listeners when the modal closes. Two, add the event listeners outside of `showEditDepartmentModal`.

I would go with number two. Your `showEditDepartmentModal` is too big. Try to break it down into smaller parts. It's name is "showEditDepartmentModal" but it does more than that - not a great idea.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding event listener n times most probably, not only one time.

### Option 1 (better):

Be sure addEventListener is called only one time, in document ready or something similar.

### Option 2 (worse, use it if you can't use option 1):

Change this:

```
allDeleteButtons.forEach(e => {
    e.addEventListener('click', (event) => {

        //console.log(event)
       
        if(event.target.classList.value == 'remove') {
            showRemoveDepartmentModal(event.target.id, event.target.alt)
        } else if(event.target.classList.value == 'edit') {
            showEditDepartmentModal(event.target.id)
        }
    })
})
```

With something similar to this:

```
function clickFunction(event) {
    //console.log(event)
       
    if(event.target.classList.value == 'remove') {
        showRemoveDepartmentModal(event.target.id, event.target.alt)
    } else if(event.target.classList.value == 'edit') {
        showEditDepartmentModal(event.target.id)
    }
}

allDeleteButtons.forEach(e => {
    e.removeEventListener('click', clickFunction);
    e.addEventListener('click', clickFunction);
})
```